# Getting Error: "Use process(css).then(cb) to work with async plugins"

Tags: react-native, expo, tailwind-css, nativewind

screens/HomeScreen.js: Use process(css).then(cb) to work with async plugins

Here is my HomeScreen.js

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

export default function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text className="text-red">HomeScreen</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

I am trying to use tailwindcss in React Native with [Nativewind](https://www.nativewind.dev/). Here is the link I am [following](https://www.nativewind.dev/quick-starts/react-native-cli).

Comment: It could be from [PR `tailwindlabs/tailwindcss#11548`: Make PostCSS plugin async to improve performance](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/11548) which was released in `v3.3.3` on July 13th. You could consider rolling back to `v3.3.2` until there is a more definitive resolution. Also, [relevant issue `marklawlor/nativewind#501`](https://github.com/marklawlor/nativewind/issues/501).

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I solved this error by changing the version to `3.3.2` and using `yarn` instead of `npm`.

Here are the commands I followed:

```
yarn add nativewind
yarn add --dev tailwindcss@3.3.2
```

Comment: Thank you Muhammad! I upgraded from Expo SDK 47 to 48 and this provided a nice quick fix to many of my bug fix issues.

Comment: Just downgrading to `3.3.2` was enough for me. No need to change to `yarn`.

Answer (score 53):

I have also got the same error when I install the `tailwindcss` with `npm`.

I have solved this by downgrading the `tailwindcss` to `3.3.2`

```
npm install tailwindcss@3.3.2 --save-dev
```

Comment: --dev is not an option for NPM. Use `npm i -D tailwindcss@3.3.2` instead.

Comment: you can use --save-dev, as Venkata writes

Answer (score 19):

in package.json change "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2", to "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",

Answer (score 7):

run this guys

```
yarn remove nativewind
yarn remove tailwindcss
yarn add postcss@8.4.23
yarn add --dev tailwindcss@3.3.2
yarn add nativewind
```

if using npm use npm instead of yarn <3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 6):

**09.08.2023 Error**

Recently have experienced the same error in Expo `SDK 49`. Current solution is to change the `tailwindcss` version to `3.3.2`.

Here is how to do it:

```
yarn add nativewind
yarn add --dev tailwindcss@3.3.2
```

Answer (score 5):

For sure the problem was the version of tailwindcss, I was using **3.3.3**, and I downgraded to version **3.3.2** and it worked just fine.

**npm i --dev tailwindcss@3.3.2** or **yarn add --dev tailwindcss@3.3.2**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I solved this error by changing the version to 3.3.2.

Here are the commands I followed:

```
npm i --dev tailwindcss@3.3.2
# or 
yarn add --dev tailwindcss@3.3.2
```

Answer (score 3):

## Remove nativewind

npm uninstall nativewind

## Remove tailwindcss

npm uninstall tailwindcss

## Add tailwindcss@3.3.2 as a development dependency

npm install --save-dev tailwindcss@3.3.2

## Add nativewind

npm install nativewind

Answer (score 2):

Also with expo you can fix it installing:

```
npm i tailwindcss": "3.3.2"  
# or 
yarn add tailwindcss": "3.3.2"
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

- yarn add postcss@8.4.23
- yarn add --dev tailwindcss@3.3.2

Assuming you've installed **nativewind** (yard add nativewind)

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add the following piece of information which may be helpful to anyone using firebase.

Even after downgrading to "tailwindcss": "3.3.2" I still got the same error. Downgrading firebase to "firebase": "9.22.2" resolved this issue.

Comment: I'm also using firebase, and I was able to upgrade to 10.1.0 without getting this same error, however I did need to update an import statement from: import { initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from 'firebase/auth/react-native'; to: import { initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from 'firebase/auth/react-native'; because I was getting an error that said: Unable to resolve "firebase/auth/react-native" from "firebase.js"

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade to **taiwindcss@3.3.2** with this command.

**npm install tailwindcss@3.3.2 --save-dev**

Then stop and start your server again.

Answer (score 0):

In your HomeScreen.js file, wrap the relevant code using the process(css).then(cb) pattern mentioned in the error message. Here is an example of how you could modify your code:

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import process from 'tailwindcss/lib';
import styles from './styles.css';

export default function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text className="text-red">HomeScreen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

// Async plugins processing
process(styles)
  .then(() => {
    // Render your components after tailwindcss plugins have been processed
    ReactDOM.render(<HomeScreen />, document.getElementById('root'));
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Make sure you replace './styles.css' with the correct path to your Tailwind CSS file containing the classNames.

By wrapping the relevant code with process(css).then(cb), you ensure that the tailwindcss plugins are processed asynchronously before rendering the components.

Remember to adjust the code as per your project structure and requirements.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, David Suzuki!

Several of your answers appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Comment: The question specifies React Native yet this code is invalid for React Native, in particular `ReactDOM.render` and `document.getElementById`