# does nativewind support responsivity?

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css, nativewind

Iam trying to use nativewind responsivity, because different mobile screens got different ratio and resolution.

What i am trying to do is:

`className="w-64 h-64 md:w-34 md:h-34 sm:w-22 sm:h-22 mb-8 rounded-full"`

But seems responsivity is not working iam using 2 android phones to test this out

First is with resolutrion 768x1280 (nexus 4)
and second one got resolution 1080x2340 (Resizable)

i got installed:
"nativewind": "^2.0.11"
"tailwindcss": "^3.3.2" // 3.3.3 was showing [err](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76688256/getting-error-use-processcss-thencb-to-work-with-async-plugins)

everything works fine except that responsivity ...

Any idea ? Thank you

It should change size of image due to screen res.